# Gradle : Copy all test dependencies to a zip file

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I am quite new to gradle, so maybe I am asking something quite easy....

I am looking for a solution to put all dependencies in scope testCompile into a zip file. I checked http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_i_make_a_zip_to_contain_dependency_artifacts but this seems to work only for runtime dependencies. I also checked http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html Chapter 16.8, but that did not work either.

When I access via `configurations.testCompile.allArtifacts.files`, my zip is always empty. When I acces via `configurations.testCompile.allDependencies` I can see all deps but I am lacking the path of the dependencies.

It is hard to believe to me, that I am the only one ever had this problems since I did not find any solution.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for me:
http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_i_make_a_zip_to_contain_dependency_artifacts

Sample task:

```
task zip2(dependsOn: 'testCompile', type: Zip) {
    from configurations.testCompile.allArtifacts.files
    from configurations.testCompile
    archiveName project.name + "_test_"+ project.version
}
```

Then run:

```
gradle test zip2
```

Zip file will be generated at:

```
build\distributions
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me too. My original code was same, but not the from configurations.testCompile. What does it do?

Comment: I don't get it. It creates a zip which is fine, but the naming is not applied. the name is alwayss project.name + "-"+ project.version. Even setting the basename attribute does not impress gradle

Comment: sorry, my fault, should be "archiveName" , I have updated my answer, PLease select my answer if you are happy with it

Comment: You might want to add a `dependsOn: ['testCompile']` to the task since it requires testCompile to be run beforehand.