# zip dependencies to a file does not work any more

Tags: file-io, gradle

basing on [Gradle : Copy all test dependencies to a zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572192/gradle-copy-all-test-dependencies-to-a-zip-file)

I created

```
task zipDeps(type: Zip) {
    from configurations.testCompile.allArtifacts.files
    from configurations.testCompile
    exclude { details -> details.file.name.contains('servlet-api') }
    exclude { details -> details.file.name.contains('el-api') }
    exclude { details -> details.file.name.contains('jsp-api') }
    exclude { it.file in configurations.providedCompile.files }
    archiveName "${rootProjectName}-runtime-dependencies_full.zip"
    doLast{
        ant.copy (toDir : "$buildDir/libs/") {
            fileset(file:"$buildDir/distributions/${rootProjectName}-runtime-dependencies_full.zip")
        }
    }
}
```

This worked fine until I migrated to gradle 2.0. If i leave that code like it was, the task is executed in the beginning and nothing happens at all. If I add << to the task and make it dependent to my war build task, at the end of the war build it claims to be up-to-date but nothing has happened.

One of my problems seems to be that the fileset to be copied is not created at all.

What can I do to get that stuff working again?

Comment: To ease my current pain I added this task to my script to have a list of dependency jars available: // just list all used jars
task zipJars(type: Sync) << {
    from files(configurations.compile.resolve() , configurations.compile.resolve() , configurations.testCompile.resolve())
    into 'libraries'
}... this task is ALWAYS up-to-date, even if it is triggered explicitly. there is something wrong ....

Answer (score 1):

The task won't be executed in the beginning, but calling `.files` resolves the configurations too early. The first `from` line needs to go (it's redundant and also calls `.files` when it shouldn't). The `doLast` block is suspicious and should probably be turned into a separate `Copy` task. Instead of the second `from` and last `exclude`, try `from (configurations.compile - configurations.providedCompile)`.